# Model.fit() ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_21 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (1708, 66)

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, keras-layer

This the code I'm working on:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import numpy
numpy.random.seed(7)

data_pixels=np.genfromtxt("pixels_dataset.csv", delimiter=',')
classes_dataset=np.genfromtxt("labels.csv",dtype=np.str , delimiter='\t')
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data_pixels, classes_dataset, test_size=0.3
```

`x_train` has a shape of `(1708, 3072)`

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       ..., 
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

`y_train` has a shape of `(1708,)`

```
array(['7', 'f', '3', ..., '6', 'o', 'O'], 
      dtype='|S5')
```

the characters of y_train are

> : , : ; ! è à ä Aa..Zz  0-9

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=3072, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

l got error after executing the following :

```
model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=150, batch_size=10)
```

the error is

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: A
```

l tried the following alternatives :
1)

```
x_train=n.array(x_train)
y_train=n.array(y_train)
```

2)

```
 model.fit(x_train,str(y_train), epochs=150, batch_size=10)
```

But l got the same error 
Then l tried another alternative

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
encoder = LabelBinarizer()
y_train = encoder.fit_transform(y_train)
```

then l get a new error which is

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_21 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (1708, 66)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following lines of code:

```
model.add(Dense(66, activation='softmax'))
```

and:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The problem lied in this that you wanted to predict a `char` which was coded as `one-hot` vector of length 66. In this case - you are setting your output to have desired length and you are using `categorical_crossentropy` loss and `softmax` activation.